# Some tutorial pages missing

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial pages for the apriltags2_ros package seem to be missing. The link to them on this page is dead: http://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros

And google searching for "apriltag continuous detection tutorial" the first result shows that the tutorials clearly existed as recently as last year. However google doesn't have a cached save of the page

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327282/some-tutorial-pages-missing/) by [jassca](https://answers.ros.org/users/43681/jassca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that the package was renamed from `apriltags2_ros` to `apriltag_ros` and that the link to the tutorials wasn't updated. I've updated the link and it now works. (The link on the sidebar to the right did work, however).

The specific tutorial that you were looking for, I believe, is the [Detection in a Video Stream](https://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros/Tutorials/Detection%20in%20a%20video%20stream) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-30**:
In the future, if you notice something in the wiki is incorrect and you know the correct information feel free update it yourself.